# On Siegel mass formula

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Edit: I asked my question on mathoverflow([On Siegel mass formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286061/on-siegel-mass-formula)), and the answers are satisfying to me.

---

I am interested deeply in the following problem:
Let $f$ be a (fixed) positive definite quadratic form;  and let $n$ be any arbitrary natural number; then find a closed formula for number of solutions to the equation $f=n$.

- For special case $f_1(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242820/jacobis-theorem-on-sums-of-two-squares-reference-request) gives a closed formula for number of solutions.
  Also you can find another formulas
  for the special cases $f_5(x,y)=x^2+5y^2$ and $f_7(x,y)=x^2+7y^2$ there.
- You can finde a close formula here for $f_2(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$, [here](https://oeis.org/A033715).
- You can finde a close formula here for $f(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84897/proofs-of-jacobis-four-square-theorem).
- By a more Intelligently search through the web; you can find similar formulas for only finite limited number of positive definite quadratic forms.
  [I think there exists such an explicit formula
  at most for $10000$ quadratic forms. **Am I right?**]

---

---

As I have mentioned (I am not sure of it!) only for finite number of quadratic forms we have such a explicit, closed, nice formula; and this way goes in dead-end for arbitrary quadratic forms.

So *Dirichlet* tries to find the (weighted) sum of such representations by binary quadratic forms of the same discriminat.

That formula works very nice for our purpose if the genera contains exactly one form. In the dirichlet formula each binary quadratic forms apears by weight one in the (weighted) sum.
More precisely let $f_1, f_2, ..., f_h=f_{h(D)}$ be a complete set of representatives for binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D < 0$; 
then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $\gcd(n,D)=1$ we have:

$$ 
\sum_{i=1}^{h(D)} 
N(f_i,n) 
= 
\omega (D) 
\sum_{d \mid n} 
\left( \dfrac{D}{d}\right) 
; 
$$

where $\omega (-3) =6$ and $\omega (-4) =4$ 
and for every other (possible) value of $D<0$ we have $\omega (D) =2$. 
Also by $N(f,n)$; 
we meant number of integral representations of $n$ by $f$; i.e. :

$$ 
N(f,n) 
:= 
N\big(f(x,y),n\big) 
= 
\# 
\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : f(x,y)=n \} 
. 
$$

---

---

I have hered that there is a generalization of dirichlet's theorem for ;quadratic forms, having more variables; due to Siegel.
I have searched through the web; 
but I have found only this link : [Smith–Minkowski–Siegel mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Minkowski%E2%80%93Siegel_mass_formula) ; 
also I confess that I can't understand whole of this wiki-article.

> Could anyone introduce me a reference in english; for Siegel mass formula ?

Comment: Given $f_1$ I'd say you want to find some [quadratic forms $f_2,\ldots,f_l$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Weil_formula) such that $h(z) = \sum_{j=1}^l \Theta_{f_j}(z) =\sum_{j=1}^l \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{2i \pi z f_j(m,m)}$ is a Hecke eigenform so its coefficients are multiplicative, and the same for $h_\chi(z) = \sum_{j=1}^l \chi(j)\Theta_{f_j}(z)$ for some characters $\chi$.

Comment: @reuns ; My dear reuns, I have added something to the main text; I look for something as follows, Is Sigel mass formula similar to the following? Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_h$ be a complete set of representatives for binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D<0$; then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{h(D)}N(f_i,n)=\omega (D)\sum_{d \mid n}\left( \dfrac{D}{d}\right);$$
where $\omega (-3)=6$ and $\omega (-4)=4$ 
and for every other (possible) value of $D<0$ we have $\omega (D)=2$. 
Also by $N(f,n)$; 
we meant number of integral representations of $n$ by $f$.

Comment: @reuns ; could you explain your comment in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @Will Jagy ; Could you help me on this question, or could you introduce me an english reference?

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is in the case $f_1$ is the quadratic form of a (fractional) ideal of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ ? (for an imaginary quadratic ideal $I = u_1\mathbb{Z}+u_2 \mathbb{Z}$ its quadratic form  is $Q(n,n) = |u_1n_1+u_2n_2|^2$,$Q(n,m) = \frac{Q(n+m,n+m)-Q(n,n)-Q(m,m)}{2}$)

Comment: @DavoodKHAJEHPOUR: Thanks for adding the note about the cross-post and answer at MO. Please see [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27641) about questions answered at MO. Perhaps you could post a brief answer and accept it, as suggested there, so that the question doesn't remain in the list of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I didn't receive an answer here, I asked my question on mathoverflow([On Siegel mass formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286061/on-siegel-mass-formula)); and there I received two satisfying answers:

---

---

[The first answer by Zurab Silagadze](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286061/on-siegel-mass-formula/286067#286067):

Try this reference [Notes on "Quadratic Forms and Automorphic Forms" from the 2009 Arizona Winter School, by J. Hanke](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5759).

P.S. See also [A proof of Siegel’s weight formula, by  A. Eskin , Z. Rudnick and P. Sarnak](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.543.8732) and [a video of Jacob Lurie's lecture "The Siegel Mass Formula, Tamagawa Numbers, and Nonabelian Poincaré Duality"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3qDTu0C7dM).

One more interesting paper is [Low-Dimensional Lattices IV: The Mass Formula, by J.H. Conway and N.J.A. Sloane](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2404971_Low-Dimensional_Lattices_IV_The_Mass_Formula).

---

---

[The second answer by Kimball Martin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286061/on-siegel-mass-formula/286176#286176) (link to [his MSE account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11323/kimball)):

There are *many, many* references on quadratic forms.  This is a huge area, depending on which way you want to go.  One of the main approaches is to construct a theta series associated to your quadratic form whose Fourier coefficients give you the representation numbers you want.  These are modular forms, and this is treated in many introductions to modular forms (in fact, I have some notes on this).

One specific reference which I think is nice is the book:

> *Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms*, by Henryk Iwaniec.

He discusses the Siegel mass formula in a simple setting and explains how you can use can get formulas for representation numbers in special cases.  In general, you can get "explicit formulas" for representation numbers in terms of Fourier coefficients of Hecke eigenforms.  You can get nice asymptotics on representation numbers this way, though the precise arithmetic of Fourier coefficients of cuspidal eigenforms is mysterious.

---

Comment: I did not notice this in March; the mass formula is available for positive forms in, for example, sage. See https://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Jagy_W/0/1/0/all/0/1  for some examples. Hmmm, I did leave a comment far above.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for introducing your related works. As you can see this answer is not mine, and after [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450607/on-siegel-mass-formula/3604120?noredirect=1#comment7408112_2450607), I just copied the answers from MO. Thank you so much for your fruitful comments, and your beautiful answers.